# XML-XSLT-XPATH : How to fetch duplicate records?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, saxon

**Greetings all,**
I am new to XML-XSLT-XPATH, therefore I stuck with the below scenario.
I want to fetch records of which name and firstname are repeating.
For example : if **User A** has **name="abc"** & **firstname="xyz"** and **User B** has **name="abc"** & **firstname="xyz"**, then it should say that User A has duplicate with User B and vice versa. *Well,* I have an input XML like below.

```
     <userlist>
        <user>abc@gmail.com
           <name>abc</name>
           <firstname>xyz</firstname>
           <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abcxy</userid>
        </user>
        <user>abc1@gmail.com
           <name>abc</name>
           <firstname>xyz</firstname>
           <email>abc1@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abc1xy</userid>
        </user>
        <user>abc2@gmail.com
           <name>abc2</name>
           <firstname>xyz2</firstname>
           <email>abc2@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abc2xy</userid>
        </user>
        <user>abc3@gmail.com
           <name>abc3</name>
           <firstname>xyz3</firstname>
           <email>abc3@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abc3xy</userid>
        </user>
</userlist>
```

"Expected Output" :

```
<duplicatUserList>
  <user>abc@gmail.com
           <name>abc</name>
           <firstname>xyz</firstname>
           <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abcxy</userid>
   </user>
    <user>abc1@gmail.com
           <name>abc</name>
           <firstname>xyz</firstname>
           <email>abc1@gmail.com</email>
           <userid>abc1xy</userid>
    </user>
</duplicateUserList>
```

It may be what I asked is very easy but as I told I am new to this XSLT-XPath.
Need XSLT to fetch duplicate records.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you well in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be seen as a variation of a grouping problem. Duplicates are simply members of groups whose size is larger than one:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/userlist">
    <duplicatUserList>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="user" group-by="concat(name, '|', firstname)">
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </duplicatUserList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to identify the duplicates. This too is a form of grouping - compare: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="dup" match="user" use="concat(name, '|', firstname)" />

<xsl:template match="/userlist">
    <duplicatUserList>
        <xsl:copy-of select="user[count(key('dup', concat(name, '|', firstname))) > 1]"/>
    </duplicatUserList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @michael.hor257k
It would be great if you give some reference site through which I can start flying with XML-XSLT-XPATH as a beginner.

Comment: I am not the right person to ask, but I believe you'd do better by investing in a good book.

Comment: Do you want a reference, or a tutorial that takes you step by step? Either way, I think both are available in much better quality in book form than as online resources, if only because someone writing a book tends to spend several months dedicated to the task and to have it carefully reviewed before publication. For a step-by-step tutorial approach, I would recommend Jeni Tennison's "Beginning XSLT 2.0", for a reference I would recommend my own "XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference" 4th edition.